# Traveling to USA via Canada

Tags: visas, usa, canada, uk-citizens

I am considering travelling from UK to Canada for 21 days and then travelling onwards to USA for a further 85 days.

I am a UK citizen so therefore have an ESTA - will this be OK for the above trip?

Comment: Do you intend to cross back into Canada after the US or are you flying back directly from the US ?

Comment: Also importantly, will you touch down in the US on your way to Canada? That has the potential to cause you to exceed your stay limits.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a visa to enter Canada ([reference](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/canada/entry-requirements)) and the US will grant you entry for 90 days following their VWP ([reference](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/usa/entry-requirements)).

Just make sure your passport is valid beyond those dates and you should be fine.

Comment: It's not so simple: for ESTA purposes, time spent in Canada between visits in the US counts against the 90-day limit. I think this isn't a problem here because Mike won't be entering the US until after leaving Canada (assuming a direct flight from the UK, without changing planes in the US), but it bears checking.

Comment: @Gilles yep, see DJClayworth's comment above :)